# Windows Media Player Classic keeps popping in the foreground

Tags: windows-7, media-player-classic

I'm using Media Player Classic Homecinema in a setup where it plays on one screen, while I'm trying to ALT-TAB between two applications on the other screen. Unfortunately, MPC keeps moving to the first place in ALT-TAB dialog although I didn't focus it.

This doesn't happen with other programs, and it also didn't happen with MPC until I switched to Windows 7. It also didn't happen in Vista.

I tried toggling MPC's "On Top" preference, but it had no effect on ALT-TAB order.

Anybody else experiencing this? It's utterly annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Download [Ultramon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/download_beta.asp).

After you install this, all your windows will have +2 new icons like in this picture:

[image]

Use the second icon to switch the window between screens, this should do the trick because this app will record your windows position.

Comment: How will Ultramon help with the tab order? I have no problems moving windows between screens.